# how to remove the element in list without knowing the index using python

Tags: python-3.x, list

here I have a list, it contains many duplicate elements I want to remove the second repeated element in list how can I remove the particular element in the list?

```
l=["a","b","a","a","a"]
here i want to remove  "a" after the second element of b(i.e a[3])

without using the index how can I remove the element in the list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search the list for the index of b and then use that as the start point for searching for a's index

```py
l=["a","b","a","a","a"]

b_index = l.index("b")
print("b index is", b_index)

first_a_after_b = l.index("a", b_index)
print("first a after b is at index", first_a_after_b)

del l[first_a_after_b]
print(l)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b index is 1
first a after b is at index 2
['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `list.index` takes `start` argument which we can use to look for `a`'s after first occurrence of `b`.

```
l = ["a","b","a","a","a"]
l.pop(l.index('a', l.index('b')+1))
# l = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```